# why page tree obtained after creating PDF using pdfBox different?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to create a `pdf document` using `pdfBox`  , a code piece for the same is mentioned below

```
 for(int j=0;j<26;j++)
         {
             PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);
             document.addPage(page);
             PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(document,page);
             content.setFont(font[j%15], 12);
             content.beginText();
             content.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700);
             content.drawString("PDF BOX TEXT CONTENT");
             content.endText();
             content.close();
             //generate data for first page

         }
```

I am able to create the pdf , however the page tree I am getting is different from the page tree I obtain for already `existing PDF file` with same content stream ,So I am not able to understand why `pdfBox` works differently while creating pdf document?If someone can enlighten in this regard , would be a great help .

The difference being :
The page tree I get when examining the `pre-existing PDF` has a depth of 3 while the tree being formed while creating PDF using `pdfBox` being 1 .So , all 26 pages I add appear to be kids of the root of the page tree I get.

Following are the files:
Preexisting file :https://www.dropbox.com/s/7o7nocg5g5o7qry/ABC.pdf
New file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/uubs36tikqkl5w1/26ABC.pdf

Comment: *pdfBox works differently while creating pdf document* - the PDF format allows multiple ways to model the same. Thus, when you are analyzing PDFs, you have to take all variants into account. That being said, you forgot to explain which differences actually are a problem for you and what you actually expect from an answer here.

Comment: Thanks mkl for suggestions.Hope now my post is clear.

Comment: The depth of a page tree is not proscribed in the PDF specification ([link to Adobe's PDF 1.7](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf)). A PDF creator can make it as complicated as it wants.

Comment: Why bother about the page tree at all? You don't need it to access individual pages, just use document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages() .

Comment: Thanks , Tilman but I was just confused with the structure , otherwise I  have tried to use the api you mentioned later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The difference being : The page tree I get when examining the *pre-existing PDF* has a depth of 3 while the tree being formed while creating *PDF using pdfBox* being 1

The PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) allows for an arbitrary depth and complexity of the page tree, cf. section 7.7.3 *Page Tree*.

In your case PDFBox opts for the most simple structure, all pages directly under the root node, while the producer of your *pre-existing PDF* has opted for a greater complexity.

**The very structure of the page tree might be due to different reasons,**

- a flat tree (like in the case of PDFBox) might be created for the sake of keeping matters simple;
- a balanced tree might be the result of optimization of page access in documents with many pages;
- inner nodes can also hold inheritable page attributes (e.g. media boxes); this can help to simplify the final page nodes;
- programs merging multiple PDFs into one may also copy the original page trees and use them as subtrees in the merged document; the result may not look very homogeneous;
- programs manipulating existing PDFs may add new pages in their preferred way while existing pages are organized as the original PDF producer preferred it; the result again may not look very homogeneous;
- programs creating PDFs might have their own way of modelling documents internally which reflects in the structures they create;
- ...

The specification explicitly mentions optimized page access and inheritable attributes as reasons for using non-flat trees. It does *not* discourage, let alone forbid their use for other reasons, though.

The OP did not share the *pre-existing PDF*, so I cannot make a more substantiated guess why that specific document uses something else than a flat tree like PDFBox.

**But in the end it doesn't really matter.** PDF consuming programs have to get along with any reasonable page tree structure and may manipulate it as they like.

Of course, if a one-page PDF has a page tree a million nodes deep, there is no reason to complain that this PDF does not e.g. display as quickly as an equivalent document with a page tree depth of 1.

**Edit** The OP meanwhile has shared the *pre-existing PDF*. The root node has 5 child nodes each of which also has 5 (or 6 in case of the last one) child nodes which are page nodes. There are no inherited attributes.

This looks like an attempt to create a balanced tree to optimize access. Considering the document size (26 pages) this does not seem necessary. Most likely the producer has the feature of creating these balanced trees to optimize large documents and simply uses this feature here, too.

PDFBox, on the other hand, does not create such balanced trees but instead a flat tree.

Comment: That was useful info !! will look more into details.

Comment: And I have attached the two files in post edit. Please have a look and provide more possible info .

Comment: I'll look at it later.

Comment: I looked at it later and edited the answer accordingly. The *pre-existing PDF* organizes its pages tree as a non-trivial balanced tree (which, therefore, is deeper than PDFBox' flat structure). This can be an advantage in case of documents with very many pages. In case of your 26 pages, though, it hardly is an advantage, probably more a burden, most likely though without consequence for any compliant PDF consumer.